# Is $X_t Y_t$ stationary?

Tags: stochastic-processes, covariance, time-series, stationary-processes

> If $X_t$ and $Y_t$ are independent and both are second order stationary processes, is
>   $X_tY_t$ also stationary?

I need to show that

i) $E(X_tY_t)$ is time independent

ii) $Var(X_tY_t)<\infty$

iii)$Cov(X_{t+h}Y_{t+h},X_tY_t)$ only depends of $h$

Then

i) $E(X_tY_t)=\mu_x\mu_y$ since $X_t$ and $Y_t$ are stationary

ii)$Var(X_tY_t)=Var(X_t)Var(Y_t)+Var(X_t)E(Y_t)^2+Var(Y_t)E(X_t)^2<\infty$ since each term in the sum is finite

iii) $\gamma_{XY}(h)=Cov(X_{t+h}Y_{t+h},X_tY_t)=E(X_{t+h}Y_{t+h}X_tY_t)-E(X_{t+h}Y_{t+h})E(X_tY_t)$

since the processes are independent
$$\gamma_{XY}(h)=[\gamma_X(h)+E(X_{t+h})E(X_t)][\gamma_Y(h)+E(Y_{t+h})E(Y_t)]-E(X_{t+h}Y_{t+h})E(X_tY_t)$$

$$=\gamma_X(h)\gamma_Y(h)+\gamma_X(h)E(Y_{t+h})E(Y_t)+\gamma_Y(h)E(X_{t+h})E(X_t)$$

I did something wrong? How I can proceed with this covariance?

Comment: Thus, $$\gamma_{XY}(h)=\gamma_X(h)\gamma_Y(h)+\gamma_X(h)\mu_Y^2+\gamma_Y(h)\mu_X^2$$